# Send touch screen event to foreground activity (only from APK)

Tags: android, android-input-method

I am trying to send touch events (clicks and motions) to the foreground application from an application with system privileges (standard upload, not rooted)

I was able to run shell scripts emulating the inputs directly from linux shell but not from my application:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)`

returns

`cannot open /dev/input/event1, permission denied`

This occurs if `cmd` is `sh /path/script-emulating-events` or `sendevent /dev/input/event1 xxxx x x`.

Since the application has android.uid.system for shared user id, it shouldn't be an android privilege issue.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be something new in Jelly Bean! The input commands have improved:

```
usage: input ...
       input text <string>
       input keyevent <key code number or name>
->       input tap <x> <y>
->       input swipe <x1> <y1> <x2> <y2>
```

It worked fine on 4.1.2

Comment: I am accepting the new am input interfaces as an acceptable solution since I did not manage to send touch screen event to system otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run those commands, you have to root your device.

Comment: OK. So is there a "send motion event" API, more reliable than this input device hack?

Comment: I have modified my su by removing the test on AID_ROOT or AID_SHELL. The problem is setuid() and setgid() also fails. Is something amiss?

adb shell ls -l /system/xbin/su*
-rwsr-sr-x root     root        64412 2012-09-17 08:12 su
-rwsr-sr-x root     root        64412 2012-09-06 12:40 su.old